# How can I restore initctl?

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

Assume I was dumb enough to accidentally unlink `/sbin/initctl`.

How can I restore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phew. Fixed it. Just download the correct `.deb` archive and extract the file manually.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/amd64/upstart/1.5-0ubuntu5